# Start Powershell(any other) in remote machine if credentials are known

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I need to perform something on a (X) user's machine from my (Y) machine and i have user name and password to it.

Detailed scenario is that i want to delete Private QUEUE which i have done via POWERSHELL and now i want that anyone in the network can run that script to delete all the private QUEUE.

any way out is welcomed

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script on a remote machine using remote PowerShell.
See [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849707.aspx) for information on `PSSession`.

```
Enter-PSSession [-ComputerName] [-Credential <PSCredential> ]
```